# Can I connect a generic Bluetooth headphone to Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

I have a generic Bluetooth headphone, I wonder if I can connect it to my Xbox 360 so I can play without bothering people around me with loud sounds.

I have tried to pair it with the "connect button" next to the USB ports, but nothing happens:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Xbox 360 does not have bluetooth built in. The connect button is for controllers only and they don't use bluetooth.

Comment: What about this? https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/set-up-bluetooth-wireless-headset

Comment: The headset supports bluetooth, but it does not connect to Xbox with bluetooth. It uses proprietary xbox wireless connection to connect to Xbox, but it can switch to bluetooth mode to connect to other, bluetooth-enabled devices. It is confusing naming on Microsoft's part.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Do you know if it's possible to connect a USB Bluetooth adapter to Xbox?

Comment: In theory you should be able to, but in reality, you would most likely need a USB Bluetooth adapter that has been tested to work with xbox360, as for external devices to work, they need to have drivers and I imagine xbox360 would have a very limited collection of bluetooth drivers, if at all.